# When KL and Reverse KL divergence become same

Tags: statistics

I’m curious if there are any two probability distributions whose kl divergence and reverse kl divergence value are the same. For obvious case, It’ll be satisfied if two distribution are the same. So I want to exclude this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Fix a probability measure $\mu$ and let $\nu=f\;d\mu$ for some density $f$. The condition for the KL divergence and reverse KL divergence of $\mu$ and $\nu$ being equal is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:Condition}
\int (1+f)\log(f)\;d\mu=0.
\end{equation}
(The expression above follows by just writing the condition so I am not writing it.)